# regexp that splits a string but ignores a quoted delimiter

Tags: regex, perl, split, delimiter, quotes

I'm writing a Perl program that needs to parse a table written in a Wiki markup language. The table syntax uses the pipe character '|' to separate the columns.

```
| row 1 cell 1    |row 1 cell 2  | row 1 cell 3|
| row 2 cell 1    | row 2 cell 2 |row 2 cell 3|
```

A cell may contain zero or more hyperlinks, whose syntax is illustrated by:

```
[[wiki:path:to:page|Page Title]]   or
[[wiki:path:to:page]]
```

Note that the hyperlink may contain the pipe character. Here, however, it is "quoted" by the [[..]] brackets.

The hyperlink syntax may not be nested.

In order to match and capture the first cell in each of these table rows,

```
| Potatoes [[path:to:potatoes]]           | Daisies           |
| Kiki fruit [[path:to:kiwi|Kiwi Fruit]]  |             Lemons|
```

I tried:

```
qr{\|                      # match literal pipe
    (.*?                   # non-greedy zero or more chars
        (?:\[\[.*?\]\])    # a hyperlink 
     .*?)                  # non-greedy zero or more chars
   \|}x                    # match terminating pipe
```

It worked, and $1 contained the cell contents.

Then, to match

```
| Potatoes            | Daisies           |
```

I tried making the hyperlink optional:

```
qr{\|                      # match literal pipe
    (.*?                   # non-greedy zero or more chars
        (?:\[\[.*?\]\])?   # <-- OPTIONAL hyperlink 
     .*?)                  # non-greedy zero or more chars
   \|}x                    # match terminating pipe
```

This worked, but when parsing

```
| Kiki fruit [[path:to:kiwi|Kiwi Fruit]]  |             Lemons|
```

I only got

```
 Kiki fruit [[path:to:kiwi
```

So evidently, given the option, it decided to disregard the hyperlink pattern and treat the embedded pipe as a column delimiter.

Here I'm stuck. And I still haven't dealt with either the possibility of the hyperlink occurring more than once in a cell, or with giving back the trailing pipe to be the leading pipe on the next iteration.

It isn't necessary that the regexp be used within Perl's `split` function -- I can write the splitting loop myself if it's easier. I see many similar questions being asked, but none seem to deal closely enough with this problem.

Comment: So your problem is that, once you've split the text on pipe characters, you can't parse the contents if they may contain a renamed link, a link, or no link. Is that right?

Comment: No, I can't split the text (the markup for an entire row of the table) into columns if they contain renamed links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common -E '$_=shift; while (
  /\| # beginning pipe, and consume it
  (   # capture 1
    (?:  # inside the pipe we will do one of these:
      $RE{balanced}{-begin=>"[["}{-end=>"]]"} # something with balanced [[..]]
      |[^|] # or a character that is not a pipe
    )* # as many of those as necessary
  ) # end capture one
  (?=\|) # needs to go to the next pipe, but do not consume it so g works
  /xg
) { say $1 }' '| Kiki fruit [[path:to:kiwi|Kiwi Fruit]]  |             Lemons|'
 Kiki fruit [[path:to:kiwi|Kiwi Fruit]]  
             Lemons
```

This seems to extract the ones you're looking for.  However, I suspect you're better off with a proper parser for this language. I'd be surprised if there wasn't something on cpan, but even if not, writing a parser for this may still be better especially as you start to get more weird things in your tables that you need to handle.

Comment: As mentioned below, I couldn't find a Perl solution in CPAN or beyond.

Comment: This answer also handles cells without a link as well as cells with multiple links. Key takeaways for me are (1) use Regexp::Common, and (2) treat the both a single non-pipe character and a balanced expression as "atomic" alternatives that occur zero or more times. Simple.